# How to design parallel multi-request in nodejs using Axios?

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to design a method for 100 users to get self data,

**API 1**

- `(xxx.xxx.xxx/api/login)`
- POST body `{"id":"xxx","password":"xxxx"},`
- response: `{"token":"xxx"}`

**API 2**

- `(xxx.xxx.xxx/api/getData)`
- POST body `{"token":"xxx"}`

How to design this case in nodejs using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)?

**Idea 1**:

Using a "for loop"

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    axios.post(api1,postdata1).then{
      //if api1 excuted successful
      axios.post(api2,postdata2)
    }
}
```

**Idea 2**:

[`axios.all`](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated)

**Idea 3**:

`await Promise.all` + `await axios.post`

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

To make the requests in parallel use `Promise.all`

```
const posts = [{api: api1, postdata: postdata1}, ... , { api: apin, postdata: postdatan}].map({a, p} => { return axios.post(a, p); });
await Promise.all(posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1** just seems too inefficient and cumbersome.

**Idea 2** is deprecated, as per the [axios github page](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated)

**Idea 3** could be considered somewhat viable, however, given that you have to do this for 100 users concurrently (100 `login` calls + 100 `getData` calls = at least 200 API calls), I would not recommend this. It may put too much pressure on the server hosting the API and will allocate too much memory for concurrent requests, might cause issues and be slow.

What I would do is use a library called Bluebird.js, which has a [`.map()` function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) which takes an array, a callback function and an object of options as params (one of which is `concurrency`, the number of promises to be executed at once) and executes the promises (requests, in this case) in batches.

Your code could look something like:

```
const BluebirdPromise = require("bluebird");

BluebirdPromise.map(usersForLogin, function(userData) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    return axios.post(`http://api.url.here/api/login`,{
        id: userData.id,
        password: userData.password
    });
},{
    concurrency: 10
}).then(function(loginResponseData) {
    console.log("Logins done");
    
    return BluebirdPromise.map(usersForLogin,function(userData,index){
        return axios.post(`http://api.url.here/api/login`,{
            id: userData.id,
            token: loginResponseData[index].token
        })
    },{
        concurrency: 10
    })

}).then(function(resultsArray){
    console.log(`All results fetched: resultsArray`);
});
```

This will hit the login API for 100 users in the `usersForLogin` array, 10 at a time, so it won't cause one big spike in the server, or the client.